# Howto print lines from a range starting from N and stopping at an address relative to the end?

Tags: sed, range

I'm trying to print lines € [N;$-M] where $ is the address of the last line :

So far, I tried this :

```
$ sed -n '71,-61 p' myLogFile
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unexpected `,'
```

and that :

```
$ sed -n '71,$-61 p' myLogFile
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `-'
```

BTW: N and M are not shell variables.

EDIT0 : My bad, `sed` is a stream editor (I thank @jhnc for this recall) therefore it cannot tell the number of lines in advance. The `$` referring to the address of the last line can only be used in text editors of the `vi` family.

So I have to use another tool to do this.

Comment: So you are basically looking to pass a shell variable value there? Not my downvote btw.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 In the sed realm, `$` is the address of the last line. I used single quotes because I don't want `$` to be interpreted but the shell. I'd like to be able to do that with a single command. No need to down-vote the question unless you explain why.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Oups sorry.

Comment: @jhnc OK I understand for `sed`. But then how does `head -n -$M` do the job if `head` does not know the total number of lines in advance ?

Comment: @jhnc Can you please convert your two last comments to an answer so you can obtain more votes ?

Comment: you can use `$` in sed but not in combination with a negative relative offset (and positive offset would make no sense!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is designed to work on piped input. It doesn't know in advance how long the input will be. Until the final line has been read, `sed` does not know how many lines remain to be processed.

It is possible to implement the desired behaviour in sed if the input is buffered before printing. For example:

```
$ ntom(){
    n=$1
    m=$2
    file=$3

    sed -nE '
        '$n' {
            # initialise buffer (avoids leading newline)
            h
            d
        }
        '$n',$ {
            # append to buffer
            H
            $!d

            # print buffer after final line read
            # delete unneeded lines off end
            x            
            s/(\n[^\n]*){'$m'}$//p
        }
    ' "$file"
}

$ ntom 71 61 myLogFile
```

but it is probably simpler to use `tail` and `head`:

```
$ tail -n +71 myLogFile | head -n -61
```

Implementations of `tail` and `head` often use a (circular) buffer on piped input too. They can be more efficient if input is seekable.

---

Also, as `ed` expects seekable input, as long as the file is not too big, you could use your original syntax with it:

```
echo '71,$-61p' | ed -s myLogFile
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
ntom(){ sed -n "$1"',${$d;:a;N;s/\n/&/'"$2"';Ta;P;D}' "$3"; }
```

Turn off implicit printing by setting the `-n` command line option to sed.

Within the range `n` to the end of the `file` create a window of `m` lines.

Once the window has been created and the end of the file it yet to occur, peel off the first line of the window print/delete it and append the next to the end of the window and repeat.

At the end of the file, delete the window.

Comment: nice. doesn't work with m=0. probably just needs `Ta;` -> `tb;ba;:b;` to be portable

Comment: @jhnc with the function as is neither n or m may be anything other than positive integers but the function could be expanded to cater for either values containing zero.

Comment: yes, m=0, you could just short-circuit to running plain tail